# x-editable submit on stop typing

Tags: javascript, x-editable

I am trying to massage x-editable to submit the context on 'stop typing'...

Here is how I do:

```
  $('.editable').on('shown', function(e, editable) {
    $(editable.input.$input).keyup(_.debounce( function(){
      <...Here should com  the correct submit code...>
      $(editable.input.$input).editable('submit', editable.options);
    } , 1000));
  });
```

The problem is that this line simply just doesn't work.

```
$(editable.input.$input).editable('submit');
```

I receive this exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
$.fn.editable   @   bootstrap-editable.js?body=1:2058
(anonymous function)    @   unobtrusive.js?body=1:225
later   @   underscore.js?body=1:846
```

Any thoughts how could I submit it?
Ideally I would like to submit using the options which were assigned by a previous editable call.

This is the previous call:

```
$('.new_association_record').editable({
  ajaxOptions: {
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'script'
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of pain I checked the source of editable...
The documentation is unfortunately not uptodate. In order to use the 'submit' message we need additional data...

So this code worked fine:

```
editable.input.$input.closest('form').submit();
```